# iOS gloss on input

Tags: html, ios, css

I have been doing some research and `-webkit-appearance: none;` removes the gloss on the iOS input as seen below:

Before: [image]

After: [image]

The issue I'm facing is I would like the down arrow to remain, but `-webkit-appearance: none;` removes this on all devices. Is there a way of only removing this gloss but not the arrow, or do I have to manually add the arrow with html + css?